# network traffic emulation tools for android

Tags: android, android-networking, network-traffic

I want a network emulator for android device to set RTT at a desired value and induce some packet loss to do some testing. I have perviously done this on ubuntu using 'netem' tool(tc command). Is there any such tool for android device? If not is there a way to achieve the same(manipulating RTT and inducing packet loss) in android?